# How many $4$-regular graphs of order $n$ can be constructed from graphs of order $n-1$ by removing two edges and adding one vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

My question is inspired by the discussion of [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723624) about the validity of inductive reasoning.

Consider a $4$-regular graph $H$ with $n$ vertices. Choose arbitrary two non-adjacent edges in $H$, say $uv$ and $xy$, where $u,v,x,y\in V(H)$. Now

1. remove these two edges,
2. then add a new vertex $w$ and four new edges: $wu,wv,wx,wy$.

We obtain a new $4$-regular graph $G$ of order $n+1$.
Let us call this process $RA$ and write $RA(H)=G$.
In the above discussion the following question was asked: whether any $4$-regular graph of order $n$ ($n\geq6$) can be obtained from a $4$-regular graph of order $n-1$ by a $RA$ procedure.

The smallest $4$-regular graph is $K_5$. The only $4$-regular graph on $6$ vertices is the octahedron graph $O$
(in the picture to the left).
For any choice of non-adjacent edges in $K_5$ we obtain $RA(K_5)=O$. There are two $4$-regular graphs of order $7$ and both of them are obtained from octahedron graph using $RA$.

[image]

However, there exists a $4$-regular graph of order $8$ which cannot be obtained from a $4$-regular graph on seven vertices.
The figure on the right shows such a graph.
In this graph, the neighbourhood of any vertex is a $3$-cycle and an isolated vertex or $K_3+K_1$
so it cannot be obtained with $RA$ from a $4$-regular graph of order $7$.

Let $K_4'$ be a graph obtained from the complete graph $K_4$ by removal of a single edge.
The following statement is true:

> Let $G$ be a $4$-regular graph of order $n$. If all vertices in $G$
> have neighbourhoods isomorphic to $K_3+K_1$ or $K_4'$, then $G$
> cannot be obtained by $RA$ from a $4$-regular graph of order $n-1$.
> If $n>5$, then the converse is also true.

Now here is my question.
Is it possible to describe the family of those $4$-regular graphs that can be obtained from $RA$ in global, but not local terms?
It is possible that this question has already been studied.

I realize that this question is somewhat vague. Here is a more specific question.
Let $R(n)$ be the number of $4$-regular graphs of order $n$ that are obtained using $RA$, $L(n)$ be the number of all $4$-regular graphs of order $n$. For which $n$ does the inequality $R(n)\leq L(n)/2$ hold?
Or also what is the behavior of the sequence $R(n)/L(n)$ at $n\to\infty$?

It seems to me that other questions are relevant here.

**Addendum dated 06/27/2023.**
I have corrected the wording of the theorem. Besides, thanks to the list of regular graphs on [Markus Meringer's website](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/markus.html) I noticed the following:

1. We saw that all $4$-regular graphs of orders $6$ and $7$ are $RA$-graphs.
2. There is exactly one $4$-regular graph of order $8$ which is not $RA$-graph. This graph is shown in the figure above. There are a total of six $4$-regular graphs of order $8$.
3. All $4$-regular graphs of order $9$ are $RA$-graphs. There are $16$ such graphs.
4. Among $59$ $4$-regular graphs of order $10$, there is only one non-$RA$-graph. This graph is shown in Figure 2 below. One can see that it is obtained from two complete graphs $K_5$.

[image]

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thank you for your comment. Very interesting considerations. Could you please specify what results about random graphs you mean?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I think it would be correct if you could give a detailed answer. For the sake of this, I will clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{R(n)}{L(n)} \to 1$: almost all $4$-regular graphs of order $n$ can be constructed from $4$-regular graphs of order $n-1$ using the operation $RA$.

When talking about the fraction of $4$-regular graphs of order $n$ with a given property, it is equivalent to phrase the question in terms of random graphs. The fraction $\frac{R(n)}{L(n)}$ becomes a probability: if we choose a uniformly random $4$-regular graph on $n$ vertices, what is the probability that it can be obtained using $RA$?

[Random regular graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_regular_graph) can be obtained using an algorithm called the "configuration model", and the asymptotic distribution of short cycles (which will be what we're interested in) was one of the first results about that model, for technical reasons.

This model creates a $4$-regular graph as follows: first, put down $n$ vertices and draw $4$ "half-edges" or "stubs" coming out of each one. Then, choose a uniformly random pairing of the $4n$ stubs (this is as simple as repeatedly choosing two unpaired stubs and pairing them). Join the paired stubs into edges, and we get a $4$-regular *multigraph*...

...and to understand $4$-regular *graphs*, Béla Bollobás (in [the paper introducing the configuration model](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(80)80030-8)) determined the asymptotic distribution of short cycles in the multigraph. Specialized to the $4$-regular case, it is: the number of $k$-cycles (at least for constant $k$, and you can push this a bit further) is asymptotically Poisson with mean $\frac{3^k}{2k}$, and cycles of different lengths are asymptotically independent.

(Why does this let us go from multigraphs to graphs? Well, a graph is just a multigraph with no $1$-cycles or $2$-cycles, which has asymptotic probability $\exp(-\frac{3^1}{2\cdot 1} - \frac{3^2}{2\cdot 2})$ in this model.)

In particular, both among $4$-regular multigraphs and (by the asymptotic independence) among $4$-regular graphs, the distribution of cycles of length $3$ tends to Poisson with mean $\frac92$ as $n \to \infty$. That's right: in an $n$-vertex $4$-regular graph, the average number of $3$-cycles tends to a constant as $n$ increases, rather then depending on $n$.

For large $n$, almost all $4$-regular graphs will have very few $3$-cycles: for example, with a limiting probability of over $99.9\%$, there will be at most $12$ of them, and we can make this probability as close to $1$ as we like by increasing the constant (and the hidden constant in the adjective "large" on $n$).

In any $4$-regular $n$-vertex graph $G$ with fewer than $\frac13 n$ $3$-cycles (which is really really almost all of them) we can be sure to pick a safe vertex to remove by picking a vertex $w$ that's not part of *any* $3$-cycles. Then its neighbors $u,v,x,y$ have no edges between them, so by deleting $w$ and adding edges $uv$, $xy$, we definitely obtain a graph $H$ such that $RA(H)=G$.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very good answer. I thought that when $n$ grows, the number of non-$RA$-graphs would be at least large enough. This turns out not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid cluttering up my question with additional details, I'll take the opportunity to give an answer to my own question.

Thanks to Misha Lavrov, we know that for large $n$ among 4-regular graphs most of them are $RA$-graphs.
We call an $RA$-graph a 4-regular connected graph, which can be obtained from a graph of smaller order using the $RA$ procedure described in my question.
Here I want to note how to construct connected $4$-regular non-$RA$-graphs of arbitrary order.
First, two general constructions.

Let $G$ be a connected $4$-regular non-$RA$-graph.

1. If $e\in E(G)$ is an edge which is not part of any triangle, then a new connected $4$-regular non-$RA$-graph can be constructed as shown in Fig. 1.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

2. If $e_1$ and $e_2$ are edges of $G$
   each not included in any triangle and $e_1\neq e_2$,
   then they are not adjacent and a new connected $4$-regular non-$RA$-graph can be constructed as shown in Fig. 2.

[image: ![enter image description here]

And now three concrete examples
of connected $4$-regular non-$RA$-graphs illustrating the application of general constructions.

[image]
[image]
[image]

One last thing. It is quite easy to prove without using lists of all connected $4$-regular graphs that there exists exactly one connected $4$-regular graph for $n=8,10,12,13,14$ and no such graph for $n=6,7,9,11$. Here $n$ is the number of vertices of the graph.